# oauth 2.0 showing authorization page again

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, oauth-provider

I am new to oauth 2.0 and reading up on it. I tried using oauth 2.0 for my app with 37signals site and ran into a problem. Now sure if its as designed. Any here is what I see.

1. User is already logged into 37signals site.
2. My app starts the oauth flow by redirecting him to 37signals site
3. An authorization page appears asking the user if he is okay with granting access to my
   app.
4. User approves and is brought back to my app. (An access token
   is also available)
5. Now, user logs out of 37signals site.
6. User tries to use my app. My app starts the oauth flow by redirecting him
   to 37signals site.
7. The user logs in using login screen.
8. He is again shown the authorization page. **Shouldn't this be skipped since
   the user approved it the first time?** Or is this as designed?

Anyway, this does not seem very user friendly to me i.e showing the approval page every time after logout.

I noticed similar behavior with twitter as well. I initially posted a similar question while using a nodejs oauth library. Then I thought its a general oauth 2.0 question.
[everyauth always triggers authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207578/everyauth-always-triggers-authorization)

Answer (score 0):

Upon initial authentication, the authentication provider, in this case 37Signals, will provide an authentication token. In company with your application key, you can use the users token to authenticate them subsequently, following the initial authentication. It's customary for OAuth providers to expire authentication tokens over time, in which case you would need to have your user re-authenticate.

Comment: The problem I have is with authorization (approval page asking for permission), not authentication (login screen). After logout, I am shown login screen (authentication) and then the approval page(authorization) again, although I approved the app earlier.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is related to the flow you are using. 37Signals supports Web Server and User-Agent flows. Which one are you using? Section 1.4.1 and 1.4.2 of the protocol docs (http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-10#section-1.4) describe the two respectively. I'm reading that to see if I can identify your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am doing the Web Server flow. Upon more reading from twitter site - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/browser-sign-flow, it looks like as designed. From that link - When the user is signed out, "Note that even if the user has already granted access to the application, the list of permissions will still be shown."

Comment: Having the list of permissions shown on subsequent log-in attempts doesn't surprise me. However, I wouldn't expect them to have to reauthorize the app with each subsequent attempt.